# My WatchOS2 app stuck on launch with Spinner

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I built a demo app on WatchOS 2.0.1, on every launch it was getting stuck with **App name on Top Left corner and spinner in middle of screen on iWatch (38mm)**. Watch is brand new and have only native apps installed till now so there should not be any issue with memory.

I **tried many times** to open the app but it was **repeatedly closing automatically after showing Spinner** for sometime. After lots of trial my Apps screen got visible and then after on every launch it worked fine without sticking on launch. I tried to double check by Force quit my app using Power button but it worked fine then after.

Then I uninstalled the app from watch and reinstalled it and same thing happened again. It started sticking. Do anyone have Idea on this? Please help on this part.

> WatchOS Version : 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing, as evidenced by it "automatically closing."

You should be able to track down the reason for the crash by examining the crash report (which can be found in the Xcode Window -> Devices pane). Alternately, you should be able to interactively debug this by running the app within Xcode.

As for it eventually no longer crashing until you deleted and reinstalled the app, the app reached a state where the reason for the crash no longer occurred. This probably is related to needing to handle some error pertaining to a path or file which it is finally able to create or access. Deleting the app recreated the condition where it repeatedly crashed again.